# Crash Running in Matlab Simulink on Mac M1MAX

Tags: macos, matlab, parallel-processing, simulink, sym

I get the following error trying to run Matlab code using parallel toolbox with Simulink.
XXX.m is a ficticious name.

This is error i get, anyone know how to solve it.

```matlab
Error using 

XXX.m

Cannot load model 'XXX.m' on parallel workers.
If this is a demo model please ensure that it is installed on the parallel workers or copy the
model file to a location outside of matlabroot

Caused by:
    A worker failed while executing a FevalOnAllFuture.
 
Warning: 2 worker(s) crashed while executing code in the current parallel pool. MATLAB may
attempt to run the code again on the remaining workers of the pool, unless an spmd block has run.
View the crash dump files to determine what caused the workers to crash.
```

Restarting the computer, Nothing works
Running on Terminal, Nothing works

Running following code:

```
%% Validation Parameters
% (1) Run the following MATLAB commands in order:
tic
rehash toolboxcache;

restoredefaultpath;

savepath
toc
% (2) Restart MATLAB and try the validation again.
```

I have Available Space 500 GB of Storage. Tried everything, Nothing Works.

Version

```matlab
ver
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MATLAB Version: 9.12.0.2039608 (R2022a) Update 5
MATLAB License Number: 40874530
Operating System: macOS  Version: 13.2.1 Build: 22D68 
Java Version: Java 1.8.0_202-b08 with Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MATLAB                                                Version 9.12        (R2022a)
Simulink                                              Version 10.5        (R2022a)
5G Toolbox                                            Version 2.4         (R2022a)
AUTOSAR Blockset                                      Version 2.6         (R2022a)
Aerospace Blockset                                    Version 5.2         (R2022a)
Aerospace Toolbox                                     Version 4.2         (R2022a)
Antenna Toolbox                                       Version 5.2         (R2022a)
Audio Toolbox                                         Version 3.2         (R2022a)
Automated Driving Toolbox                             Version 3.5         (R2022a)
Bioinformatics Toolbox                                Version 4.16        (R2022a)
Bluetooth Toolbox                                     Version 1.0         (R2022a)
Communications Toolbox                                Version 7.7         (R2022a)
Computer Vision Toolbox                               Version 10.2        (R2022a)
Control System Toolbox                                Version 10.11.1     (R2022a)
Curve Fitting Toolbox                                 Version 3.7         (R2022a)
DDS Blockset                                          Version 1.2         (R2022a)
DSP HDL Toolbox                                       Version 1.0         (R2022a)
DSP System Toolbox                                    Version 9.14        (R2022a)
Database Toolbox                                      Version 10.3        (R2022a)
Datafeed Toolbox                                      Version 6.2         (R2022a)
Deep Learning Toolbox                                 Version 14.4        (R2022a)
Econometrics Toolbox                                  Version 6.0         (R2022a)
Embedded Coder                                        Version 7.8         (R2022a)
Filter Design HDL Coder                               Version 3.1.11      (R2022a)
Financial Instruments Toolbox                         Version 3.4         (R2022a)
Financial Toolbox                                     Version 6.3         (R2022a)
Fixed-Point Designer                                  Version 7.4         (R2022a)
Fuzzy Logic Toolbox                                   Version 2.9         (R2022a)
Global Optimization Toolbox                           Version 4.7         (R2022a)
HDL Coder                                             Version 3.20        (R2022a)
Image Acquisition Toolbox                             Version 6.6         (R2022a)
Image Processing Toolbox                              Version 11.5        (R2022a)
Industrial Communication Toolbox                      Version 6.0         (R2022a)
Instrument Control Toolbox                            Version 4.6         (R2022a)
LTE Toolbox                                           Version 3.7         (R2022a)
Lidar Toolbox                                         Version 2.1         (R2022a)
MATLAB Coder                                          Version 5.4         (R2022a)
MATLAB Compiler                                       Version 8.4         (R2022a)
MATLAB Compiler SDK                                   Version 7.0         (R2022a)
MATLAB Report Generator                               Version 5.12        (R2022a)
Mapping Toolbox                                       Version 5.3         (R2022a)
Mixed-Signal Blockset                                 Version 2.2         (R2022a)
Model Predictive Control Toolbox                      Version 7.3         (R2022a)
Motor Control Blockset                                Version 1.4         (R2022a)
Navigation Toolbox                                    Version 2.2         (R2022a)
Optimization Toolbox                                  Version 9.3         (R2022a)
Parallel Computing Toolbox                            Version 7.6         (R2022a)
Partial Differential Equation Toolbox                 Version 3.8         (R2022a)
Phased Array System Toolbox                           Version 4.7         (R2022a)
Powertrain Blockset                                   Version 1.11        (R2022a)
Predictive Maintenance Toolbox                        Version 2.5         (R2022a)
RF Blockset                                           Version 8.3         (R2022a)
RF PCB Toolbox                                        Version 1.1         (R2022a)
RF Toolbox                                            Version 4.3         (R2022a)
ROS Toolbox                                           Version 1.5         (R2022a)
Radar Toolbox                                         Version 1.2         (R2022a)
Reinforcement Learning Toolbox                        Version 2.2         (R2022a)
Requirements Toolbox                                  Version 2.0         (R2022a)
Risk Management Toolbox                               Version 2.0         (R2022a)
Robotics System Toolbox                               Version 4.0         (R2022a)
Robust Control Toolbox                                Version 6.11.1      (R2022a)
Satellite Communications Toolbox                      Version 1.2         (R2022a)
Sensor Fusion and Tracking Toolbox                    Version 2.3         (R2022a)
SerDes Toolbox                                        Version 2.3         (R2022a)
Signal Processing Toolbox                             Version 9.0         (R2022a)
SimBiology                                            Version 6.3         (R2022a)
SimEvents                                             Version 5.11        (R2022a)
Simscape                                              Version 5.3         (R2022a)
Simscape Driveline                                    Version 3.5         (R2022a)
Simscape Electrical                                   Version 7.7         (R2022a)
Simscape Fluids                                       Version 3.4         (R2022a)
Simscape Multibody                                    Version 7.5         (R2022a)
Simulink 3D Animation                                 Version 9.4         (R2022a)
Simulink Check                                        Version 6.0         (R2022a)
Simulink Coder                                        Version 9.7         (R2022a)
Simulink Compiler                                     Version 1.4         (R2022a)
Simulink Control Design                               Version 6.1         (R2022a)
Simulink Coverage                                     Version 5.4         (R2022a)
Simulink Design Optimization                          Version 3.11        (R2022a)
Simulink Design Verifier                              Version 4.7         (R2022a)
Simulink Desktop Real-Time                            Version 5.14        (R2022a)
Simulink PLC Coder                                    Version 3.6         (R2022a)
Simulink Report Generator                             Version 5.12        (R2022a)
Simulink Test                                         Version 3.6         (R2022a)
Stateflow                                             Version 10.6        (R2022a)
Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox               Version 12.3        (R2022a)
Symbolic Math Toolbox                                 Version 9.1         (R2022a)
System Composer                                       Version 2.2         (R2022a)
System Identification Toolbox                         Version 9.16        (R2022a)
Text Analytics Toolbox                                Version 1.8.1       (R2022a)
UAV Toolbox                                           Version 1.3         (R2022a)
Vehicle Dynamics Blockset                             Version 1.8         (R2022a)
WLAN Toolbox                                          Version 3.4         (R2022a)
Wavelet Toolbox                                       Version 6.1         (R2022a)
Wireless HDL Toolbox                                  Version 2.4         (R2022a)
```

Comment: So the worker crashed while running a script that is so secret you can’t even tell us the name. How could you expect any help from us here? “Tried everything, Nothing Works.” So if you tried everything, what do you expect us to help with? Anything I could come up with to try, you already tried, right? —— This is the sort of thing you should take up with the MATLAB help desk, that’s what you’re paying for.

Comment: @CrisLuengo thank you, name is not secret, just long and confusing.

Comment: Anyway, if you want useful help, you create a [mre], and you list exactly which you things you tried and what their results were.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Overall, I have a simulink model, change few parameters, run simulation again and again from matlab, after getting data from simulink simulation, then do some calculation, and create plots and tables for report in Latex.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are problems with that version of MacOS. I suggest upgrading to the latest version.

Comment: Indeed, I updated. I run the code a few times and it is working fine. I need to still try more to see if it breaks simulation like before.

Comment: ```matlab
Operating System: macOS  Version: 13.3.1 Build: 22E261 .
```